# Country code is not changing when number is given in React-Phone-Input 2

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, package

My Code is something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { code: 91 };
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.code);
    return (
      <PhoneInput
        country={this.state.code}
        value="1425652"
        onChange={(phone) => console.log({ phone })}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

But it is not taking the updated country code.
[screenshot of console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhX2F.png)

Answer (score 3):

You should handle the state in a better way.

```
import React from 'react';
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-input-2'
import 'react-phone-input-2/lib/style.css'


class App extends React.Component {
  state = { phone: '' };

  handleOnChange = (value, data, event, formattedValue) => {
    console.log(data.dialCode);
    this.setState({ phone: value });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <PhoneInput
        country={'us'}
        value={this.state.phone}
        onChange={this.handleOnChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: But I want to send the country code as number and not string

Comment: You need to extract the country code from the entered value. Am I right?

Comment: Yes... I need to extract as well as in the country I need to send integer value that I am getting from API response instead of string value.

Comment: @Shayane please check the updated code. You can get the country code by `data.dialCode`.

Comment: Thank you for your response.... I am aware that data.dialCode will give me the code.... But the when I try console.log(this.state.phone), I get phone number with code.... Whereas I need only phone number and code needs to be separated.... Which is one of my main issues.... 
secondly I am getting the phone number and code separately from an API.... I need to show them in the <PhoneInput> but unable to do so.....

Answer (score 2):

Run this to get the number without the dial code

```
handleOnChange(value, data, event, formattedValue) {
  this.setState({ rawPhone: value.slice(data.dialCode.length) })
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Its not updating because the  **value="1425652"** is static, if you want to update what your type, remove it or initialize the value in state a state and update when the onChange event is triggered for instance; if the state is some thing below

this.state={
phone:''
},
Then you can update in the onChange Event like this!! onChange={(phone) => this.setState({
phone:phone
}))}